# Clock does not run

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I would like to programm a simple clock with python and tkinter indicating local and utc time in the same window. As you can see on the screenshoot, first clock local time is not running, but the second clock below utc time is running well. At the moment I can not figure out the error. Maybe someone of you can help me.

Thanx a lot!

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from time import strftime
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Python Clock')

def localtime():

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    string = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    mark.config(text = string)
    mark.after(1000,localtime)

    mark = Label(root, 
        font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
        pady=150,
        foreground = 'blue')

   mark.pack(anchor = 'center')
localtime()

def time_utc():

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    string = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    mark.config(text = string)
    mark.after(1000, time_utc)

    mark = Label(root, 
        font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
        pady=150,
        foreground = 'blue')

    mark.pack(anchor = 's')
time_utc()
mainloop()
```

[image: First clock local time, second clock utc time]

Comment: You code is not valid at the moment - `mark` is used before it is defined in both methods. Please provide valid code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create the `mark` labels inside the functions. Instead you need to create them once at the top level, and then just call `config` and `after` inside each function to modify them on each loop:

```
def localtime():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    string = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    locallbl.config(text = string)
    locallbl.after(1000,localtime)


def time_utc():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    string = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    utclbl.config(text = string)
    utclbl.after(1000, time_utc)

utclbl = Label(root,
    font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
    pady=150,
    foreground = 'blue')

locallbl = Label(root,
    font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
    pady=150,
    foreground = 'blue')

locallbl.pack(anchor = 'center')
utclbl.pack(anchor = 's')

localtime()
time_utc()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanx a lot it works! The problem was mark inside the function.